# Cannot connect to NodePort URL with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm just trying out a very simple example of NodePort, using minikube on an Apple M1 machine. I basically create a single-node k8s cluster via minikube, then create a 1-pod deployment, and NodePort service. The NodePort URL keeps loading for me. Below are the commands I use.

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.25.2 on Darwin 12.4 (arm64)
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.23.3 preload ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v17-v1...: 419.07 MiB / 419.07 MiB  100.00% 5.49 MiB
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.23.3 on Docker 20.10.12 ...
    ▪ kubelet.housekeeping-interval=5m
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
    ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default


$ kubectl create deployment nginx-deployment --image=nginxdemos/hello
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created


$ kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --type=NodePort --port=80
service/nginx-deployment exposed


$ minikube service nginx-deployment
  Starting tunnel for service nginx-deployment.
  Opening service default/nginx-deployment in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.

=> This opens the URL in the browser (e.g. http://192.168.49.2:32739/), but it keeps loading forever
```

When I SSH into the node, I can curl the pod IP without problems.

```
$ minikube ssh
Last login: Thu May 26 10:09:35 2022 from 192.168.49.1

# This is the IP of the running pod
docker@minikube:~$ curl -sI 172.17.0.3 | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I also see that the service is binded to the pod:

```
$ kubectl describe service nginx-deployment

Name:                     nginx-deployment
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=nginx-deployment
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=nginx-deployment
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.109.174.147
IPs:                      10.109.174.147
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32739/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.3:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: check if port-forward set from NodePort 32739 to Pod Target port 80

Comment: are you able to get any response if you curl on 10.109.174.147?

Comment: show you service manifest. show minikube node ip / port mapping

Comment: @Nayan: as you can see the Endpoints is "172.17.0.3:80", that means the port mapping between NodePort and Pod port 80 is already set, isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by switching to use Docker Desktop kubernetes. Seems like minikube doesn't play well with Apple M1.